# How to control displayed content (video/images) with a range slider?

Tags: javascript, three.js, slider, css-animations

I'm trying to create a component that lets the user control the displayed videos/images through a range slider. Content should change smoothly between A/B and C/D preferable if there's a way to add a fast forward blur or a morph animation in between the blocks. 
[image: State-1]
[image: State 2]

Comment: Your question reads a bit as “I need someone to code this for me”... what have you coded so far?

Comment: Nothing. I want a brief explanation from experts on how to approach this.

Comment: Just a tip if you don't mind, I'd recommend you to read about [How do I ask a question on StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), otherwise it's quite probable you won't receive any answer but negative voting